# Warning message if file name already exists when creating a pdf file

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following macro to create a PDF file from my Excel spreadsheet:

```
Sub PDF_01()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

This macro works fine so far. However, once I have created the file "test.pdf" and I run the macro again it will overwrite the first file without giving any warning message such as "The filename already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?".

Do you know how I can include this message in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dir` to see if the file already exists and then give the user an alternative choice, i.e

```
Dim StrIn As String
StrIn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.pdf"

If Len(Dir(StrIn)) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=StrIn, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
    MsgBox "file already exists"
    ' do something else
End If
```